# Replacing letters in a string with for loops

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to loop through a String array replacing each letter in the word with a corresponding letter. I have an array of classes that store a letter called letter Occurrence, I have one for each letter that appears in my original string, which is stores 23 chars of the alphabet(Z never appears in my original string) I've then sorted my class from the most common letters to the least common letters that appear.

Here's the original string of text that I want to change:

`vaoyelsy lsty aajp l a k urd  aoofeia upd, kxflup lo oatqaosavailmjakqp ks oatqao frdap ks l k, l dtq dfisoak tva aoyifqqia fja lo dafo toakqp. toakqp tva aoy fqqia fja lo trdlqdao, ks k da lja acfkp da fpoumqflk b atra b da lois.pmath aksaoiy l daj. aq daoa a fkskapp k luo tra, k luo yap, k luo jfia, k da tojqd b luo oaaqfkc. iwtyp tva  daaobui jfia. lk'q kiy fva luo toa, uq fva luo atoq p aii.qda loa lu tva, da loa lu oa rrumfas, da app lu fva. uq da app lu tva da loa oaa lu oa. lvaoqy lo p p  oaaslj. q p lq loqfbfrtqflk,  aktkra.fq p lybui oaaslj. daoa p l aiavfpflk aoa, l dfp, l dtq. uq a oa aobarqiy tmmy`.

Heres an output of the order the letterOccurence array.

```
a - 12.3342175066313%
o - 6.23342175066313%
l - 5.570291777188329%
q - 3.8461538461538463%
f - 3.580901856763926%
k - 3.580901856763926%
p - 3.4482758620689653%
d - 3.183023872679045%
t - 3.050397877984085%
u - 2.7851458885941645%
i - 2.3872679045092835%
s - 1.7241379310344827%
y - 1.7241379310344827%
v - 1.5915119363395225%
j - 1.4588859416445623%
r - 1.3262599469496021%
b - 0.9283819628647214%
m - 0.7957559681697612%
c - 0.2652519893899204%
e - 0.2652519893899204%
h - 0.1326259946949602%
w - 0.1326259946949602%
x - 0.1326259946949602%
```

And heres my code replacing the letters.

```
char[] letterFrequency = {'e','t','a','o','i','n','s','h','r','d','l','c','u','m','w','f','g','y','p','b','v','k','j','x','q','z'};
    String codeBreak = "";

    for(int cnt = 0; cnt < words.length;cnt++){

        for(int i = 0;i < letterOccurences.size(); i++){
            words[cnt] = words[cnt].replace(letterOccurences.get(i).GetLetter(),letterFrequency[i]); 
        }

        codeBreak += " ";
        codeBreak += words[cnt];
    }
    System.out.println("~~~~" + codeBreak);
```

So in theory all the letter 'a' should be changed to e, however this is not the case, this is the message im getting outputted.

```
ybfubapu apfu bbkp a b n dfv  bfflblb dpv, njladp af fbfobfpbyblaykbnop np fbfobf lfvbp np a n, a vfo vllpfbn fyb bfulloolb lkb af vblf ffbnop. ffbnop fyb bfu loolb lkb af ffvaovbf, np n vb akb bplnp vb lpfdyolan g bffb g vb aflp.pybfv bnpbflu a vbk. bo vbfb b lnpnbpp n adf ffb, n adf ubp, n adf kllb, n vb ffkov g adf fbbolnp. lkfup fyb  vbbfgdl kllb. an'o nlu lyb adf ffb, do lyb adf bffo p bll.ovb afb ad fyb, vb afb ad fb ffdylbp, vb bpp ad lyb. do vb bpp ad fyb vb afb fbb ad fb. aybfou af p p  fbbpak. o p ao afolglffolan,  bnfnfb.lo p augdl fbbpak. vbfb p a blbylplan bfb, a vlp, a vfo. do b fb bfgbfolu fyyu.
```

as you can see the second letter was originally an 'a' and should be replaced with a 'e' however its displaying 'b'

Comment: have you stepped through a debugger to find your problem? this looks to me as a simple task to solve using a debugger. step through the code and analyze the status of the `words` array to find the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are reassigning `words[cnt] = words[cnt].replace()` it looks like you first change `a` to `e` and then change this `e` to a `b`.

You should loop through all the letters in `words[cnt]`, translate it into a new letter and append that to a `StringBuilder builder`. Then, after the loop is finished, assign `words[cnt]` the value of `builder.toString()`.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int pos = 0; pos < words[cnt].length(); pos++) {
   builder.append(translateLetter(words[cnt].charAt(pos), letterFrequency));
}
words[cnt] = builder.toString();
```

You probably also want `replaceAll` instead of `replace`, but after making the `StringBuilder` change this won't matter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i understand what was going on now but i'm not sure where you're getting the translated Letter part from as i can't see on java docs.

Comment: @user3649280 Oh sorry, I put that function call there as a stand in for a function you will need to write to take a letter and convert it to its translation based on the letterFrequency array.

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the whole string every time, this means that after replacing an a with an e when you then replace all e occurrences later you are over writing the original replacements again.

Keep your input and output Strings / Arrays separate.

On an additional note I'm assuming the output is txt speak because there appear to be 6 single letter words, good English only has two single letter words a and I this may skew any frequency analysis, or indicate that a Caeser cypher was not used.